# What is this incredibly efficient ground cover?

Tags: identification, ground-cover

I moved some soil from one part of my garden to another recently. This seems to have caused fairly aggresive appearing of this ground cover (weed?): (leaves are smallish, 1cm long)

[image]

In next two pictures you can see it 'in action':

[image]

[image]

Here you can see it growing 'through' another plant:

[image]

What is this plant?

Could it be CHICKWEED Stellaria media?

Comment: Where in the world are you? Location can be important for identification.

Comment: I am near Copenhagen, Denmark, european hardness zone 8a.

Comment: @NiallC. I see you are very good at IDing weeds (I read some answers of yours). What do you think?

Comment: Growth pattern looks too "dense" for _Stellaria media_ and your plant's leaves look yellower than I'd expect. https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/29042/26 has some photos of S. media for comparison.

Comment: Is stem round? Hairs just on one line (changing place between nodes?) Leaves without hairs?  If it is Stellaria media, I would expect to see few flowers (on such large surface, but difficult to see them). Note a weed: you can eat it: it is very good. Birds like it.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, I am going to try to get new photos and data related to what you said by tomorrow evening.

Comment: I don't think it's Stellaria. It resembles a small ground-covering veronica that I have in my own lawn.

Comment: Did you notice if there were flowers and what color? Also, maybe you can check in a few steps to see if it is chcikweed https://www.wikihow.com/Identify-Chickweed

Comment: Three monts ago this was just bare land area, and I think it is too early for flowers to appear, so no flowers seen. @False Btw, excelent guide that you linked to!

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Due to unforeseen circumstances (travel) I can't get any new data in next few days. I will post any new info as soon as I come back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea; Ludwigia palustris an aquarium plant...[image: Ludwigia palustris]

Comment: I doesn't agree with the identification. I still think is one of the Stellaria (but not S. media, because it seems to have a square stems.

Comment: Are the stems woody? If not, then it's not Euonymus.

Comment: The stems are not woody at all. Very soft carpet.

Comment: Do these guys have their own roots?  Are they trailing like vines?  I thought Impatiens at first, Stellaria as well looks similar. They should be having flower buds by now, yes?  Do any of your neighbors have this in their yard?  I would, however, remove all ground cover from the base of your little tree.  Copenhagen, Denmark?  What a nice fall you are having...pull out an entire plant to include roots, hopefully buds.  And send a picture of that?

Comment: Here's what I meant by a [creeping veronica] (https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1008/4432/products/Creeping_Speedwell_2048x2048.jpg?v=1479871818)

Comment: @stormy: I think it is better if you left the old answer (and delete it), instead of rewriting the answer. Now most comments are wrong. Nothing wrong on deleting answers.